# How to create csv file without blank rows

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a below code which is creating a csv file:

```
import csv

# my data rows as dictionary objects
mydict = [{'branch': 'COE', 'cgpa': '9.0', 'name': 'Nikhil', 'year': '2'},
          {'branch': 'COE', 'cgpa': '9.1', 'name': 'Sanchit', 'year': '2'},
          {'branch': 'IT', 'cgpa': '9.3', 'name': 'Aditya', 'year': '2'},
          {'branch': 'SE', 'cgpa': '9.5', 'name': 'Sagar', 'year': '1'},
          {'branch': 'MCE', 'cgpa': '7.8', 'name': 'Prateek', 'year': '3'},
          {'branch': 'EP', 'cgpa': '9.1', 'name': 'Sahil', 'year': '2'}]

# field names
fields = ['name', 'branch', 'year', 'cgpa']

# name of csv file
filename = "university_records.csv"

# writing to csv file
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv dict writer object
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)

    # writing headers (field names)
    writer.writeheader()

    # writing data rows
    writer.writerows(mydict)
```

Running the above code is giving below excel sheet

[image]

It contains blank rows as well. How can I remove these blank rows. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should create a dataframe with your dict, and then just use

```
pd.to_csv(name_of_dataframe, sep=your_columns_sep)
```

Comment: This is certainly an option. I would not go as far as to say one *should* convert, though. Not everybody is willing to depend on pandas ;)

Comment: You're right I should have said you 'could' ahah, but it makes everything so much easier when dealing with excel files I couldn't help myself (:

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `newline=''` in the `with open ...` does the trick:

```
import csv

my_dict = [{'branch': 'COE', 'cgpa': '9.0', 'name': 'Nikhil', 'year': '2'},
          {'branch': 'COE', 'cgpa': '9.1', 'name': 'Sanchit', 'year': '2'},
          {'branch': 'IT', 'cgpa': '9.3', 'name': 'Aditya', 'year': '2'},
          {'branch': 'SE', 'cgpa': '9.5', 'name': 'Sagar', 'year': '1'},
          {'branch': 'MCE', 'cgpa': '7.8', 'name': 'Prateek', 'year': '3'},
          {'branch': 'EP', 'cgpa': '9.1', 'name': 'Sahil', 'year': '2'}]

fields = ['name', 'branch', 'year', 'cgpa']

filename = "foo_bar.csv"

with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fields)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(my_dict)
```